# Does Google BigQuery charge for GetQueryResults()

Tags: c#, .net, google-bigquery, nuget-package-restore

I am running the Query in C#.NET application using .NET API library which is added through Nu-Get package manager.

**My Query:**

```
Select * From DataSetID.TableID LIMIT 10000
```

**Note:** Data Processing for the above query is 1GB (get it from Web-UI).

When i am running the same query in C#.NET application, i am able to get ~5600 Rows in single request, then i am passing `PageToken` to `GetQueryResults` method and get remaining records. (Through pagination).

So There are 2 Query request to get 10K records.

How Google charges for Data Processing either 1 GB for query nor 2 Requests * 1GB = 2GB ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BQ charges per query issued, not per call to GetQueryResults. You can call GetQueryResults as many times as you like and it won't change your bill.

Answer (score 0):

Since you run multiple jobs, each job has it's own cost plan. In the response of the [getQueryResults](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/getQueryResults) you have `cacheHit` attribute that tells you if you hit the cache, and it was free, or not.

You can always check based on `jobId` the costs of a query using the BQ console tool or the API.

Comment: I am running single job with Select statement and getting the result of the job using `getQueryResults`. Is cost includes only for Select statement nor each getQueryResults?

Comment: you need to check each getQueryResults and if cacheHit is true than cost is zero, if not there are costs involved, and you can obtain the costs looking up the jobId.