# Does QueryRequest's Execute() method return the entire result (and not paginate it)?

Tags: c#, .net, google-bigquery

When I execute my `QueryRequest` object, I get a `totalRows` of around 110,000 while the response rows are around 38,000. So I am not receiving the entire result and must do paging.

But I see that my `QueryRequest` object has no `startIndex` property.

How can I receive the entire result set?

I am using a Premium version of Google Analytics. Does Google still return 10MB of data with each request?

**UPDATE**: I don't think my question is a duplicate. What I meant by the question was how can I get a specific page of results when my `QueryRequest` has no `startIndex` property.

```
JobsResource j = null;
QueryRequest qr = null
...
j.qr.Query = "SELECT examplecolumns FROM myTable";
QueryResponse response = j.Query(qr, projectId).Execute();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Google BigQuery charge for GetQueryResults()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335308/does-google-bigquery-charge-for-getqueryresults)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the getQueryResults() method to fetch the rest of the results.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/getQueryResults

Comment: Your answer is correct. Google's Big Query docs is however, very confusing.

Comment: Yeah, I agree they're confusing. We'll see if we can improve them soon.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return the entire result set because Google has general quota limits for all of their API's:

General Quota Limits (All APIs)

The following quota limits are shared between the Management API, Core Reporting API, MCF Reporting API, Metadata API, and Real Time Reporting API.

50,000 requests per project per day – can be increased
10 queries per second (QPS) per IP.

In the Developers Console this quota is referred to as the per-user limit. By default, it is set to 1 query per second (QPS) and can be adjusted to a maximum value of 10. If the per-user limit is set to a value larger than 10 QPS, the Google Analytics quota policy will still take effect and limit per-user requests to 10 QPS.

If your application makes all API requests from a single IP address (i.e. on behalf of your users) you should consider using the userIP or quotaUser parameters with each request to get full QPS quota for each user. See the query parameters summary for details.

For more information have a look at this link: [Configuration and Reporting API Limits and Quotas](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/limits-quotas)

You can also find more information on the subject here:[Querying Data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_DynamoDB_Model_QueryRequest.htm)

The following additional limits apply for querying data.

Maximum tables per query: 1,000
Maximum query length: 256 KB

Comment: Thanks for the info. I updated the question to be more specific.

Comment: The general quota limits mentioned above do not apply to BigQuery. (BigQuery quota is documented at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy.) But that's not the source of this user's problem, since the user is only trying to make a handful of API calls.

Answer (score 0):

The query / getQueryResults methods are used to push some of the waiting for job completion into the server. Clients may see faster notification of job complete when using this mechanism, and will receive the first page of the query results in that response, avoiding the need for one additional round trip to fetch the data.

The general mechanism for using these apis, in pseudo code, is:

```
response = query(...)
while (!response.jobComplete) {
  response = getQueryResults(response.jobReference);
}
moreData = false
do {
  // consume response.rows
  moreData = response.pageToken != null
  if (moreData) {
    response = getQueryResults(response.jobReference, response.pageToken)
  }
} while (moreData)
```

Note that some type safe languages will be more difficult to code this, as the first response in that do loop may be a `QueryResponse` or a `GetQueryResultsResponse` type, depending on whether the query job finished within the initial timeout on the `query()` call, or whether it finished within the `while (!response.jobComplete)` polling loop.